# How are inline functions in stack traces recorded and symbolicated?

Tags: inline, crash-reports, symbolicatecrash

When I pause at a breakpoint, Xcode seems to be able to see inline functions, and they're marked with "[inline]". Further, when I do CPU profiling, it's able to see inline functions. However, when I record and symbolicate a crash with PLCrashReporter and `symbolicatecrash`, it doesn't seem to include the inline functions. `backtrace` + `backtrace_symbols` also skips inlined functions. How does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DWARF debug symbols represent information on inlining with `DW_TAG_inlined_subroutine` and `DW_AT_inline`. When stack traces are being generated and functions are resolved the DWARF tree can be walked to collect this inlining information.